# Making rule on dates for vector points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, fields-attributes, date, if-statement

In QGIS, I would like to create a rule-based on dates for some vector points. These points have a field for dates, in the format `dd/mm/yy`. The rule would be such that if a date is less than a certain date then I expect to see one symbol and if not then another symbol. How can achieve it?

Answer (score 4):

We are starting from a common issue here: your date is not a date. It is a string representing a date. And strings cannot be compared by `smaller than`, `less than` or similar operators. Another issue is that you cannot specify the century, by giving only the last two numbers of the year. By default QGIS interprets this as 19xx. So you need to add or substract the centuries to your year.

You can do the following:

1. Convert your string to a date via `to_date("yourstringdatefield",'dd/MM/yy')`
2. Add or substract a century: `to_date("yourstringdatefield",'dd/MM/yy') + to_interval('100 years')`
3. Compare it, e.g. `to_date('24/09/2019','dd/MM/yyyy') < (to_date("yourstringdatefield",'dd/MM/yy') + to_interval('100 years'))`